# Error getting user info in actions-on-google

Tags: node.js, webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, actions-builder

I'm developing an application for the Google Assistant, but always when I try to get the user info, like name or location, after I get the user permissions the application crash and in the next times when I launch the application with the permissions granted crash again in the same step.

```
app.handle('create_user', async (conv) => {
  const payload = conv.user.params.tokenPayload;
  // write user name in session to use in dialogs
  conv.user.params.name = payload.given_name;
  const email = payload.email;
  if (email) {
    try {
      conv.user.params.uid = (await auth.getUserByEmail(email)).uid;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code !== 'auth/user-not-found') {
        throw e;
      }
      // If the user is not found, create a new Firebase auth user
      // using the email obtained from the Google Assistant
      conv.user.params.uid = (await auth.createUser({email})).uid;
    }
    const userDoc = dbs.user.doc(conv.user.params.uid);
    const orderHistoryColl = userDoc.collection(orderHistory);
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      await orderHistoryColl.doc(options[i]).set(
          {option: options[i], count: 0});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi there! It is a little unclear exactly what your problem would be. StackOverflow works best if you can provide detailed information about the problem you're seeing. This includes showing the code that is causing the problem, error messages when the problem occurs, screen shots of the relevant intents, and sample conversations illustrating what you're trying to do and what is actually happening.

Comment: I have tried using actions.type.permission, it's show me the message about the permission and the conditions to accept, but later the application close automatically. I can't send you my code because all is developed inside Actions Builder. But I have tried in differents ways and I got the same result when ask for permissions

Comment: Updating your question with whatever you can, and then noting in the comments that you've done so, is the best approach. Trying to explain things in comments can make it more confusing. Again, the more you can provide - the better our chances are of being able to help. If all you have are the graphical elements in Action Builder, then posting screen shots can help. See "[ask] a good question?"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in this case it's a little bit difficult, because it's all in my personal profile and I can't get you the access. In the screenshot you only are going to see red a message that says, the 'app-name' can't respond in this moments. 
I will try in a different way and put here a piece of code

Comment: If you expand each conversational turn (arrow to the right on that turn) you should be able to see additional diagnostic info. And this is all logged to Google Cloud, which has a link towards the upper right. All  of that can be useful. If you wrote any code, then seeing that code will also help.

Comment: @Prisoner the error that it's giving me is 
`Unsuccessful webhook call due to client issue: Error querying agent endpoint. State: URL_UNREACHABLE, reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx. { "responseJson": { "error": "Cannot read property 'given_name' of undefined" } }`